# The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly on Azure dev ops build step

Tags: .net-core, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

I am receive this error on Azure dev ops  in the step of a build "run build and test".

In my local work s fine.

If desactivate the test the build works fine.

This is the error:

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/app/Infrastructure.deps.json'. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Interop.CheckIo(Error error, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategyctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.Create(String path) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.WriteDepsFile(String depsFilePath) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.ExecuteCore() [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(176,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj]
```

Someone has have this error to try run the test on the build?

The project test only have one test, but this test have a file that i am using in the test:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="invoices.xlsx">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>
```

Thank you!